# Handwriting text effect in Flash AS3(Dynamic)

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone suggest me the Code for Handwriting Text Effect in flash AS3. I want the writing effect with dynamic text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make every symbol you need to be written as a symbol and then mark them for "Export for actionscript" if Flash. Then you'd add them to a container like this:

```
  private function writeDynamicText(str:String):void
    {
        var calculatedX:int = 0;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            var LetterClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(str.charAt(i)) as Class;
            var letter:LetterClass = new LetterClass();
            letter.x = calculatedX;
            container.addChild(letter);
            calculatedX += letter.width;
        }
    }
```

For this code to work you must name the letter i symbol "i" and so on.